# MFMEDIASOURCE_HAS_MULTIPLE_PRESENTATIONS MediaSource Characteristics

Tags: windows, ms-media-foundation

I have implemented a media source with the characteristics MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_PAUSE | MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SEEK.

This is working fine.Seek and pause a file is also working.

Now I have added a characteristic MFMEDIASOURCE_HAS_MULTIPLE_PRESENTATIONS, after adding this characteristic seek and pause is not working. is there any other thing I have to take care?

My current characteristic variable looks like,

*pdwCharacteristics =  MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_PAUSE | MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SEEK | MFMEDIASOURCE_HAS_MULTIPLE_PRESENTATIONS;

Please give some suggestion.

Best Regards,

Sharad

Comment: Just as a guess, can you also add MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SKIPFORWARD and  MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SKIPBACKWARD capabilities?

Comment: thanks for the reply  Aleksey ... I tried adding MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SKIPFORWARD and MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SKIPBACKWARD capabilities but result is same...

Comment: as per microsoft link.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms694277.aspx  .....    To skip forward or backward in a playlist, call IMFMediaSource::Start or IMFMediaSession::Start with the MF_TIME_FORMAT_ENTRY_RELATIVE time-format GUID. This capability applies only when the MFMEDIASOURCE_HAS_MULTIPLE_PRESENTATIONS flag is present. but i am not getting MF_TIME_FORMAT_ENTRY_RELATIVE time-format GUID in start method.